# Textbox does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

problem in code

2 files:
Register.aspx
Register.aspx.cs

Register.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="HSE_Monitoring_Application.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <h2>
                        Create a New Account
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Use the form below to create a new account.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
                    </p>
                    <span class="failureNotification">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </span>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="RegisterUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                         ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                    <div class="accountInfo">
                        <fieldset class="register">
                            <legend>Account Information</legend>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" 
                                     ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                     ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p class="submitButton">
                            <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Create User" 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup" OnClick="onSubmitNewUser"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                </CustomNavigationTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

Problem:
cannot see Textbox 'UserName' from Register.aspx.cs class:

```
void onSubmitNewUser(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strcon = "connect_information";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("storelogin", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("username",  UserName.Text);
            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("password", ConfirmPassword.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add(p1);
            com.Parameters.Add(p3);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Labelinfo.Text = "registered successful";
        }
```

Comment: Can you kindly provide your mark up code

Comment: what do you mean by markup code?

Comment: The aspx file  code you have now included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also  likely  that you will get  a hard time  getting  the ConfirmPassword text box contents..Because your controls  are buried inside another container,  you have to  be rewarded after  some  little excavation..Lets start  digging......

Using the wizard  which is already accessible locate your text box

```
    TextBox  UserName= (TextBox)CreateUserWizard.FindControl("UserName");
```

//Then  use it as you want.Hope this helps.