# TextBox control does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my .aspx page I have the following code in my ListView control;

```
    <%@ Page Title="User Registration" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="registration" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<!-- Your Code goes here -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="menu" Runat="Server">
    <!-- Your Code goes here -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="main_content" Runat="Server">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                 <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="username" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>                

        <asp:sqldatasource ID="semester1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT modules.cats_points, modules.module_id, modules.compulsory, modules.module_name, modules.year FROM Courses INNER JOIN courses_vs_modules ON Courses.course_id = courses_vs_modules.course_id INNER JOIN modules ON courses_vs_modules.module_id = modules.module_id INNER JOIN student_records ON Courses.course_id = student_records.course_id AND modules.year = student_records.year AND courses_vs_modules.course_id = student_records.course_id WHERE (student_records.user_id = @user_id) AND (modules.semester = 1)"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [students_vs_modules]([user_id], [module_id]) VALUES (@user_id, @module_id)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="user_id" Name="user_id" Type="Int32"></asp:QueryStringParameter>
            </SelectParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="module_id" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:sqldatasource>

        <asp:sqldatasource ID="semester2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT modules.cats_points, modules.module_id, modules.compulsory, modules.module_name, modules.year FROM Courses INNER JOIN courses_vs_modules ON Courses.course_id = courses_vs_modules.course_id INNER JOIN modules ON courses_vs_modules.module_id = modules.module_id INNER JOIN student_records ON Courses.course_id = student_records.course_id AND modules.year = student_records.year AND courses_vs_modules.course_id = student_records.course_id WHERE (student_records.user_id = @user_id) AND (modules.semester = 2)"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [students_vs_modules]([user_id], [module_id]) VALUES (@user_id, @module_id)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="user_id" Name="user_id" Type="Int32"></asp:QueryStringParameter>
            </SelectParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="module_id" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:sqldatasource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="emergency_contact" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT student_records.user_id, student_records.f_name, student_records.l_name, emergency_contact.em_contact_id, emergency_contact.relationship_id, emergency_contact.contact_name, emergency_contact.phone_number, emergency_contact.address_1, emergency_contact.address_2, emergency_contact.town_city, emergency_contact.county, emergency_contact.postcode, emergency_contact.country, relationship.relationship FROM student_records INNER JOIN emergency_contact ON student_records.user_id = emergency_contact.user_id INNER JOIN relationship ON emergency_contact.relationship_id = relationship.relationship_id WHERE (student_records.user_id = @user_id)"
          UpdateCommand="UPDATE [emergency_contact] SET [relationship_id]=@relationship_id, [contact_name]=@contact_name, [phone_number]=@phone_number, [address_1]=@address_1, [address_2]=@address_2, [town_city]=@town_city, [county]=@county, [postcode]=@postcode, [country]=@country WHERE [user_id]=@user_id ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="user_id" Name="user_id" Type="Int32"></asp:QueryStringParameter>
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="relationship_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="contact_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="phone_number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="address_1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="address_2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="town_city" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="county" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="postcode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="emergency_contact_list" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT relationship_id, relationship FROM relationship"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

        <asp:View ID="em_contact_view" runat="server">
        <h1>Emergency Contact</h1>
            <asp:ListView ID="em_contact_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="emergency_contact" >
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">user_id:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("user_id") %>' runat="server" ID="user_idTextBox" /><br />
                        f_name:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("f_name") %>' runat="server" ID="f_nameTextBox" /><br />
                        l_name:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("l_name") %>' runat="server" ID="l_nameTextBox" /><br />
                        em_contact_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("em_contact_id") %>' runat="server" ID="em_contact_idLabel1" /><br />
                        relationship_id:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("relationship_id") %>' runat="server" ID="relationship_idTextBox" /><br />
                        contact_name:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("contact_name") %>' runat="server" ID="contact_nameTextBox" /><br />
                        phone_number:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("phone_number") %>' runat="server" ID="phone_numberTextBox" /><br />
                        address_1:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("address_1") %>' runat="server" ID="address_1TextBox" /><br />
                        address_2:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("address_2") %>' runat="server" ID="address_2TextBox" /><br />
                        town_city:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("town_city") %>' runat="server" ID="town_cityTextBox" /><br />
                        county:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("county") %>' runat="server" ID="countyTextBox" /><br />
                        postcode:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("postcode") %>' runat="server" ID="postcodeTextBox" /><br />
                        country:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("country") %>' runat="server" ID="countryTextBox" /><br />
                        relationship:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("relationship") %>' runat="server" ID="relationshipTextBox" /><br />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ID="UpdateButton" />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <span>No data was returned.</span>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">user_id:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("user_id") %>' runat="server" ID="user_idTextBox" /><br />
                        f_name:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("f_name") %>' runat="server" ID="f_nameTextBox" /><br />
                        l_name:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("l_name") %>' runat="server" ID="l_nameTextBox" /><br />
                        relationship_id:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("relationship_id") %>' runat="server" ID="relationship_idTextBox" /><br />
                        contact_name:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("contact_name") %>' runat="server" ID="contact_nameTextBox" /><br />
                        phone_number:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("phone_number") %>' runat="server" ID="phone_numberTextBox" /><br />
                        address_1:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("address_1") %>' runat="server" ID="address_1TextBox" /><br />
                        address_2:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("address_2") %>' runat="server" ID="address_2TextBox" /><br />
                        town_city:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("town_city") %>' runat="server" ID="town_cityTextBox" /><br />
                        county:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("county") %>' runat="server" ID="countyTextBox" /><br />
                        postcode:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("postcode") %>' runat="server" ID="postcodeTextBox" /><br />
                        country:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("country") %>' runat="server" ID="countryTextBox" /><br />
                        relationship:
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("relationship") %>' runat="server" ID="relationshipTextBox" /><br />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">user_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' runat="server" ID="user_idLabel" /><br />
                        f_name:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("f_name") %>' runat="server" ID="f_nameLabel" /><br />
                        l_name:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("l_name") %>' runat="server" ID="l_nameLabel" /><br />
                        em_contact_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("em_contact_id") %>' runat="server" ID="em_contact_idLabel" /><br />
                        relationship_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("relationship_id") %>' runat="server" ID="relationship_idLabel" /><br />
                        contact_name:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("contact_name") %>' runat="server" ID="contact_nameLabel" /><br />
                        phone_number:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("phone_number") %>' runat="server" ID="phone_numberLabel" /><br />
                        address_1:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("address_1") %>' runat="server" ID="address_1Label" /><br />
                        address_2:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("address_2") %>' runat="server" ID="address_2Label" /><br />
                        town_city:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("town_city") %>' runat="server" ID="town_cityLabel" /><br />
                        county:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("county") %>' runat="server" ID="countyLabel" /><br />
                        postcode:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("postcode") %>' runat="server" ID="postcodeLabel" /><br />
                        country:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("country") %>' runat="server" ID="countryLabel" /><br />
                        relationship:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("relationship") %>' runat="server" ID="relationshipLabel" /><br />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ID="EditButton" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style=""><span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" /></div>
                    <div style="">
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">user_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' runat="server" ID="user_idLabel" /><br />
                        f_name:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("f_name") %>' runat="server" ID="f_nameLabel" /><br />
                        l_name:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("l_name") %>' runat="server" ID="l_nameLabel" /><br />
                        em_contact_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("em_contact_id") %>' runat="server" ID="em_contact_idLabel" /><br />
                        relationship_id:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("relationship_id") %>' runat="server" ID="relationship_idLabel" /><br />
                        contact_name:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("contact_name") %>' runat="server" ID="contact_nameLabel" /><br />
                        phone_number:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("phone_number") %>' runat="server" ID="phone_numberLabel" /><br />
                        address_1:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("address_1") %>' runat="server" ID="address_1Label" /><br />
                        address_2:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("address_2") %>' runat="server" ID="address_2Label" /><br />
                        town_city:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("town_city") %>' runat="server" ID="town_cityLabel" /><br />
                        county:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("county") %>' runat="server" ID="countyLabel" /><br />
                        postcode:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("postcode") %>' runat="server" ID="postcodeLabel" /><br />
                        country:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("country") %>' runat="server" ID="countryLabel" /><br />
                        relationship:
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("relationship") %>' runat="server" ID="relationshipLabel" /><br />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ID="EditButton" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="em_contact_next" runat="server" Text="Next" />
        </asp:View>

        <asp:View ID="semester_1_view" runat="server">
        <h1>Semester 1</h1>
        <asp:DataList ID="semester_1_datalist" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                module_name:
                <asp:Label ID="module_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("module_name") %>' />
                <br />
                year:
                <asp:Label ID="yearLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("year") %>' />
                <br />
<br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var limit = 3;
                    $(function () {
                        $('[id*="module_semester_1"]').on('change', function (evt) {
                            if ($('[id*="module_semester_1"]:checked').length > limit) {
                                this.checked = true;
                                alert('cannot select more than ' + limit);
                            }
                        });
                    });
    </script>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="module_semester_1" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester1" DataTextField="module_name" DataValueField="module_id" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
            <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="btnnext2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btnnext2_Click" />
        </asp:View>

        <asp:View ID="semester_2_view" runat="server">
        <h1>Semester 2</h1>

        <div runat="server">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="moduleselect" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester2" DataTextField="module_name" DataValueField="module_id" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:DataList ID="semester_2_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                module_name:
                <asp:Label ID="module_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cats_points") %>' />
                <br />
<br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
            <br />
                <asp:Button ID="uploadbutton" runat="server" Text="Choose Modules" OnClick="uploadbutton_Click" CssClass="submitbtn" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CssClass="submitbtn" />
        </div></asp:View></asp:MultiView>
</div>
            </div>
            </asp:Content>
```

I'm trying to update fields in the database table using C#, I have the following C# code, however I am receiving the error stating that TextBox control `contact_nameTextBox` does not exist in current context and I'm not sure why, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void em_contact_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        string Name_data = contact_nameTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439331/textbox-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Try to give the name along with ID, and then try.

Comment: @PM. I'm sorry what do you mean by this? Do you mean `string Name_data = contact_nameTextBoxID.Text;`? Sorry I'm a newbie to programming in general

Comment: I mean instead of **<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("contact_name") %>' runat="server" ID="contact_nameTextBox" />** Use **<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("contact_name") %>' runat="server" ID="contact_nameTextBox" name="contact_nameTextBox" />**

Comment: I tried that method and still receiving the same error.

Comment: Oh my bad, I did not see that your text box is inside the ListView. You need to get the children of your control first. Let me put whole thing separately. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you´re trying to access it from a protected void, you need to create an instace of it

```
protected void em_contact_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        contact_nameTextBox.Text = new textBox();
        string Name_data = contact_nameTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: This will create another instance, and will not give the value of the existing textbox.

Comment: Is that textbox on the same class/form as the code with you´re calling it?

Comment: I am still getting the same error using this method

Comment: Sometimes happened to me on VS, take a look in the designer file and see if VS created an entry in there for the text box? Make sure you don't have another file somewhere with a similar declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void em_contact_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    myConnection.Open();      

    ListView parent = (ListView)sender;

    if(parent != null)
       var contact_nameTextBox = (TextBox)(parent.FindName("contact_nameTextBox"));


    string contact_Name = contact_nameTextBox.Text;
   //Your code
}
```

I have not tested this code, but hope with some small changes it should work.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error on `AllChildren` should this be renamed to something else. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: I tried the code but was still receiving errors. I have added my whole aspx file to the original question, maybe it is something else causing the errors as I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Tried to run your code, but it has too many fields. Can you try it with very simple object, lets say only with two properties and see if that works for you?